# Java - KeyListener Events not firing

Tags: java, event-handling, applet

I have begun to write a simple platform game in java. As a test, I wrote this simple
program that moves a rectangle around the applet when you press the arrow keys. The key events have not been firing at all. Here's the code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Game extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
  //setup data
  Thread t;
  Image buffimg;
  Graphics draw;
  Dimension dim;

  //game variables
  int charx = 400;//rectangles X and Y positions
  int chary = 50;
  boolean leftArrow = false;
  public void init()
  {
        setSize(800, 500);
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
       addKeyListener( this );
  }
  public void run()
  {
        while(true)
        {
          repaint();
          moveChar();//move the rectangle
          try {
                t.sleep(1000/30);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) { ; }
        }
  }
   public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) 
   { 
       int k = e.getKeyCode();
       if(k == 37)
       {
           leftArrow = true;
           charx--;
       }

   }
   public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ) 
   { 
       if(e.getKeyCode() == 37)
       {
           leftArrow = false;
       }
   }
   public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) 
   {
   }
  public void moveChar()
  {
      //move rectangle on left arrow key press
      if(leftArrow == true)
      {
          charx--;
      }  
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
      g.drawRect(charx, chary, 100, 100);
  }
  public void update (Graphics g)
  {
      //double buffering

      // initialize buffer
      if (buffimg == null)
      {
          buffimg = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
          draw = buffimg.getGraphics ();
      }
      // clear screen in background
      draw.setColor (getBackground ());
      draw.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
      // draw elements in background
      draw.setColor (getForeground());
      paint (draw);
      // draw image on the screen
      g.drawImage (buffimg, 0, 0, this);
  } 
}
```

Why aren't they firing and how should I fix this?

Comment: I can move the rectangle to the left withouth problems. Are you sure you ran the latest version of your code?

Comment: Yes, Could it be a problem with my eclipse settings?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that seemed to have fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.requestFocusInWindow(); // end of init(), or better, in start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code. It works as it should.

The problem is you need to press the mouse on the drawing area to focus it first before it can receive events.

To do it automatically, use this command: requestFocusInWindow()

Comment: sorry, during time I was testing your code, Andrew posted the answer.

Comment: +1 for *"I was testing your code"*  I didn't bother with that, mine was just an educated guess.  ;)